# How to vertically center my name over an image

Tags: html, css

My name at the right is supposed to be in front of the image that is currently below it. How do I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/L18cunx2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="one columns">
            <input class="bbar" placeholder="search">
        </div>
        <div class="eleven columns person">
            <span><a class="username">Rajat Sharma</a></span> <img alt="" src="logout.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The fiddle is nice, but you need to put include your css here as well.

Comment: Even in the fiddle you'll have to trim the CSS. It's literally hundreds of lines of unrelated rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a little unclear on your question but will do the best I can to answer. You are going to want to create a stacking context within the div.person container.

You can set position:relative to the div.person span, and div.person img elements. You then set the z-index to 1 for div.person span. This will put the span above the image.

Example Code:

```
div.person span, div.person img {
   position:relative
}

div.person span {
   z-index:1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
.username {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
```

}

This fixes it, but it's pretty hackish. I've set the element in the span to display block, but that's not really the intention of a span element.

EDIT: I may have misunderstood the question. You're asking about vertical centering, rather than horizontal centering, which is what my code does. But then you go on to ask, it seems, about the z-index. Can you clarify what it is you're looking for, please?